# Accept job offer/opportunity meeting knowing not to accept it for now?

Tags: communication, europe, self-employment, academia

I was contacted by the academic director of the most prestigious institute at our university (with strong contacts to world-leading corporations) and was asked for a meeting. The director wanted to get to know me and it would be about the (job) opportunities in the institute for me.

On the one hand I would like to hear about the opportunities, on the other hand I am already planning to potentially found a business with partners. Therefore, I probably would not accept any offer from the institute for the time being anyway. However, I find their subject area very interesting and could very well imagine working/researching there if I were to continue my studies in the future.

Should I still attend the meeting, but communicate in the 1:1 meeting that I intend to found a business? Or should I communicate this directly in my invitation response and not attend the meeting?

Is there any general advice to "keep the door open"? Especially without stepping on the person's toes, since there is a strong disparity in terms of the status position (student <-> professor).

Comment: "should" is a strong word. Don't ask yourself what you should do. Ask yourself what you want to do. As to your partnership, I know this is not what you were asking, but I recommend you and your potential partner read the following book before you go any further with it: https://www.amazon.com/Partnership-Charter-Start-Right-Business/dp/0738208981 (I'm not affiliated with that book in any way, but this is the book I wish I had read before a friend and I started our own company).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If someone wants to speak with you about a job opportunity, there is nothing wrong with attending that meeting, even if you think it is really unlikely that you'd accept an offer from them.

Now, if you know with absolute, 100% certainty that you wouldn't accept a job (you are leaving the city or country, you're already committed to going back to school, etc.,) you should inform the other person prior to the meeting, so they can determine if it is worth their time.  But in any other situation, there is nothing wrong with speaking with them: the person inviting you knows that their's is just one of many options you have.

On the other hand, you shouldn't attend a meeting if it is a waste of YOUR time (though sometimes there are still "political" reasons to take the meeting).  That said, the fact that you'd "like to hear about the opportunity" and "could imagine working" there makes it seem that it is worth your time.  Who knows what's being offered - maybe it is such a great opportunity that you change your mind.

Comment: Perfect answer, nothing I could add

Answer (score 1):

It's not a terrible idea to accept the meeting even if you have no intention of joining, though as with previous answers, if it's a zero possibility say so beforehand. Couple of reasons to still accept:

- Grow your network and make a connection — you/they may be able to connect with new individuals in the future.
- Interviews are two-way streets — one of the core answers you can seek out is what perceived qualities/skills do you have that are valuable
- You never know — they may make an offer you couldn't refuse or potentially be interested in your business venture as a consultancy